# How can I fix this overfull hbox in the align* environment?

Tags: align, margins

I have an align* environment with some equations and justifications. But it's giving me an overfull hbox error because the equations are so long. How do I fix this?

```
\begin{align*}
     F_k & = F_{k - 1} + F_{k - 2} & \text{by the definition of the sequence}\\
     & = {\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1+{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k-2}-{\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1-{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k-2} + {\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1+{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k-1}-{\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1-{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k-1} & \text{by our inductive hypothesis}\\
     & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}+\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-1}\right)-\left(\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}+\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-1}\right)\right) & \text{by algebra}\\
     & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}\left(1+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}\left(1+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right) & \text{by more algebra}\\
     & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2}-\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{k-2}\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^{2}\right) & \text{even more algebra}\\
     & = {\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1+{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k}-{\cfrac {1}{\sqrt {5}}}\left({\cfrac {1-{\sqrt {5}}}{2}}\right)^{k} & \text{last bit of algebra}\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We can't reproduce your problem since we haven't any information about your document. So, please be so kind and extend your code fragment to small but complete compilable document.

Comment: that just means the equation is wider than the page but you have given no information about the fonts or page size. But simply split it into more, shorter, lines.